# va_args not accepting signed integer in C

Tags: c, string, variadic-functions, elf, unsigned-integer

I was designing my kernel using C. While making the `kprintf` function (a function like `printf` but works with the kernel) I saw that signed integers (precisely the data type is `long`), `va_args` is converting them to `unsigned long`.

Here's a snippet of the code:
`kPrint.c`

```c
#include <stdarg.h>

// skipped some lines not needed for this question
// ...

/******************
 * global variables needed for number to string conversion
 * ***************/
// store the converted string temporarily
static char convertedString[30];

// store the index of the filled portion
static char numberIndex;

// TODO: Create function like printf but which works here
_Bool kprintf(const char* stringFormat, ...) {
    char* strPtr = (char*)stringFormat;
    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, stringFormat);

    while (*strPtr != 0) {

        switch (*strPtr)
        {
        case '\e':
            // printf() also ends the execution
            return 1;
        case '%':
            switch (*(strPtr + 1))
            {
            // signed decimal integer
            case 'd':
            case 'i':
                kprintf(IntToString(va_arg(arguments, long long))); // stringify the integer
                // *problem* here
                strPtr += 2;
                break;

            // unsigned decimal integer
            case 'u':
                kprintf(uIntToString(va_arg(arguments, uint64_t))); // stringify
                strPtr += 2;
                break;

            // will implement U & L case later
            // unsigned hexadecimal
            case 'x':
            case 'X':
                kprintf(uHexToString(va_arg(arguments, uint64_t))); // stringify
                // doesn't work now
                strPtr += 2;
                break;

            // will implement U & L case later
            // 6 numbers after decimal
            case 'f':
            case 'F':
                kprintf(DoubleToString(va_arg(arguments, double), 6)); // stringify
                // doesn't work now
                strPtr += 2;
                break;

            // 2 numbers after pt
            case 'g':
            case 'G':
                kprintf(DoubleToString(va_arg(arguments, double), 2));
                strPtr += 2;
                break;

            case 'c':
                kPrintChar((char)va_arg(arguments, int));
                //
                strPtr += 2;
                break;

            // another string
            case 's':
                kPrintfHelper(va_arg(arguments, char*)); // just to prevent recursion
                strPtr += 2;
                break;

            case '%':
                kPrintChar('%');
                strPtr += 2;
                break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            kPrintChar(*strPtr);
            strPtr++;
        }
    }
    va_end(arguments);
    return 0;
}

void uIntToStrHelper(uint64_t num) {
    if (num < 10)
    {
        convertedString[numberIndex++] = num + '0';
        convertedString[numberIndex] = 0;
        return;
    }

    uint8_t numIndexCpy = numberIndex;

    while (num > 0) {
        convertedString[numberIndex++] = (num % 10) + '0';
        num /= 10;
    }

    char swpIndex = (numberIndex - 2 + numIndexCpy) / 2;
    numberIndex = numberIndex - swpIndex - 1 + numIndexCpy;

    while (swpIndex >= numIndexCpy) {
        convertedString[swpIndex] = convertedString[swpIndex] + 
            convertedString[numberIndex];

        convertedString[numberIndex] = convertedString[swpIndex] -
            convertedString[numberIndex];

        convertedString[swpIndex] = convertedString[swpIndex] -
            convertedString[numberIndex];
        
        swpIndex--;
        numberIndex++;
    }

    convertedString[numberIndex] = 0;
}

char* uIntToString(uint64_t num) {
    numberIndex = 0;
    uIntToStrHelper(num);
    return convertedString;
}

char* IntToString(long long num) {
    numberIndex = 0;
    if (num < 0) {
        convertedString[numberIndex++] = '-';
        num = -num;
    }

    uIntToStrHelper(num);
    return convertedString;
}
```

**EDIT:** Added `IntToString` and `uIntToString`.

(I don't know the correct way to do this, but it suffices)

**Overview of the problem:**
cases for 'd' and 'i' show the place of the problem.
Function prototype of `IntToString`:

```c
char* IntToString(long long num);
// part of the reason why I used long long as va_arg data type
// had also tried with long but with no luck :(
```

I have tried `IntToString` & `uIntToString` functions on a linux machine and they work the way intended.

**NOTE:** I have not tested `kprintf(const char* stringFormat, ...)` in a controlled & easily debuggable environment like the other 2 functions mentioned just above.

Other functions like `DoubleToString` and `uHexToString` have not yet been tested but it should not change/be related to the question anyway.

`kPrintfHelper` is a function just like `kprintf` but does not do any checking and just prints the string

**My Environment**
Compiler: `x86_64-elf-gcc`
Flags (aka CFLAGS): `-ffreestanding -mno-red-zone -m64`

Linker: `x86_64-elf-ld`

I use `qemu-system-x86_64` to run the final executable.

### Tests

I have tried the following cases:

1. Normal unsigned case

```c
kprintf("Number: %d\n", 1234);
```

Output:

> Number: 1234

2. Does not work but the output seems like `va_args` is doing some weird unsigned `int` math (further proved by test 5 that it was indeed `va_args`, IMO)

```c
kprintf("Number: %d\n", -1234);
```

Output:

> Number: 4294966062

3. Works as intended

```c
kprintf("Number: %d\n", 1099511627775);
```

Output:

> Number: 1099511627775

4. **BUT** This

```c
kprintf("Number: %d\n", -1099511627775);
```

Output:

> Number: 1099511627775

5. *AND here*

```c
kprintf("Number: %s\n", IntToString(-1234));
```

Output:

> Number: -1234

Comment: Its "like" not an exact copy of `printf` + it keeps things simple for now.

Comment: Unseen `IntToString()` may be defective for -1099511627775.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] especially `IntToString`.

Comment: Point to be noted but I just tested out `kprintf("Number: %s\n", IntToString(-1099511627775));` and it works fine with the output as `Number: -1099511627775`

Comment: The call `kprintf("Number: %d\n", -1234);` is incorrect because `%d` extracts a `long long`. It must be kprintf("Number: %d\n", -1234LL);

Comment: @Kaz actually adding `LL` solved the problem but why should converting an `int` to `long long`  change the value, shouldn't it be like implicit type casting? An why should it affect only -ve numbers?

Comment: "An why should it affect only -ve numbers?" is unfounded as the 2 tests are insufficient to support that conclusion.  Try `kprintf("Number: %d %d %d %d\n", 1234, 5678, 123, 456);`

Comment: Have done a number of tests and concluded that it affects only **negative 32-bit numbers**. Gotta check `va_args` docs throughout the internet for this behavior and the reasons for it. (Although the reason is already mentioned by @dbush, still why only -ve numbers? Why this injustice?)

Comment: @idiot BTW: `printf("%lld", -1234);` shows the exact same problem as your code at least on my platform. `%lld` expects a 64 bit integer but -1234 is a 32 bit integer. BTW you should change your user name. This question is too good for this user name.

Comment: Side note: `numberIndex` being a global variable is somewhat poor design.

Comment: Aside:  re _"Why this injustice?"_   Attempting to characterize the behaviors associated with `va_args` as an _injustice_ seems melodramatic, don't you think?

Comment: @Jabberwocky, there you go, changed my user name to '0xdead'. IK about `numberIndex` being global, its also used in the untested `DoubleToString` function and I will focus on improving it. Was just concerned about the printing part till now which is solved, will focus on the design after it works properly.

Comment: @0xdead  Variadic arguments in C have no type safety. Certain conversions are performed on certain argument types (e.g.  a value of `short` becomes `int`, or `float` becomes `double`). After that, there is no type checking or conversion. The `va_arg` macro has no idea what object was actually passed; it blindly trusts that the indicated type is correct and just interprets the bits from the argument space accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call `kprintf("Number: %d\n", -1234);` is incorrect because `%d` extracts a `long long`. It must be `kprintf("Number: %d\n", -1234LL);`.

-1234 is a 32 bit operand. The problem could be that this is being passed in a 64 bit aligned word, but not being sign extended to 64 bits.

So that is to say, the -1234 value in 64 bits needs to be `fffffffffffffb2e`, but the 32 bit parameter is producing a `00000000fffffb2e` image on the stack, which is 4294966062.

According to this hypothesis, we would have to pass -1000 to obtain the observed 429496629, however. It bears no relation to -1234.  Something else could be going on, like garbage bits being interpreted as data.

The behavior is not well-defined, after all: you're shoving an integer of one size into a completely typeless and unsafe parameter passing mechanism and pulling out an integer of a different size.

Answer (score 3):

The type of the value you're passing in for your `%d` specifier doesn't match what `va_arg` is expecting.

You're telling `va_arg` to expect a `long long`, but `1234` and `-1234` have type `int`.  These types are different sizes, so `va_arg` is pulling more bytes from the call stack than you put on.

The standard format specifiers have size modifiers so they can handle different size types.  You'll need to implement something similar.